# Suitable control algorithm for Air Muscle based joint?

Tags: control, pid, air-muscle

I have a joint actuated by an antagonistic pair of Pneumatic Muscles.

[image: Pneumatic Muscle Joint]

There are two valves per muscle, one to fill and one to empty each muscle. The joint has an angle sensor, and each muscle also contain an air pressure sensor.

What is a suitable control algorithm set up?

- A PID controller controlling the valve orifice sizes?
- A PID controller controlling the mass flow rate?
- A PID controller controlling the pressure using two PID pressure controllers?
- A Fuzzy Logic controller?
- A Neural Network?

Comment: Do you have a mathematical model of the system?

Comment: @user1154 - Sadly, I do not.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that the cog will remain a fixed distance from the wall and that only one air muscle can be activated at a time?

Comment: @DaemonMaker - Yes, the cog will remain a fixed distance from the wall. But both muscles may have some pressure in them at the same time. That depends on the controlling algorithm suggested in the answer. I do not want to put a constraint on that.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Wikipedia page on [Pneumatic artificial muscles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pneumatic_artificial_muscles):

> This is one of the major advantages; the mathematical model that supports the PAMs functionality is a non-linear system, which makes them much easier [citation needed] then conventional pneumatic cylinder actuators to control precisely. The relationship between force and extension in PAMs mirrors what is seen in the length-tension relationship in biological muscle systems.

I'm not convinced that non-linear functionality would make them easier to control, in fact in my experienced, non-linear systems are *substantially less easy* to control than linear systems.

This article references a number of papers which may form the basis of useful research into the kinematics of these devices. In particular [Pneumatic Artificial Muscles: actuators for robotics and automation](http://lucy.vub.ac.be/publications/Daerden_Lefeber_EJMEE.pdf) look slike it would be quite useful as a review of the research, including plenty of citations for following up.

I would guess that these air muscles suffer many of the same myths and prejudices that [Proportional Pneumatic Motion Control](http://hydraulicspneumatics.com/other-technologies/5-myths-pneumatic-motion-control) system have, so reading up on these systems might be useful too.